# StackExchange Redis Failover Corrupts Connection

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, amazon-elasticache

I'm using the StackExchange.Redis client and a static IConnectionMultiplexer  as recommended to connect to the primary endpoint of an AWS ElastiCache server (2 nodes with failover).
`ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("someredis.clustercfg.use1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379");`
When we failover (using the test "Failover Primary" option), writes via the connection permanently fail until we re-create the connection.

Is that expected?
Is there a configuration option we're missing?